# Apache camel Multipart issue

Tags: apache-camel, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a form with pdf file through angular 4 as

[image]

The request is a multipart/form-data request

i am using spring boot , apache camel-servlet with my route as

```
 rest("/notice").description("Upload Multiple Report via camel and netty")
                        .post().route().unmarshal().mimeMultipart()
                        .to("direct:uploadReportProcessor");
```

and in my processor i have

```
Map<String, DataHandler> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachments();
```

and then i am trying to write to a file as below:

```
    byte[] bytes = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(dh.getInputStream());

Path path = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\" + dh.getName());
Files.write(path, bytes);
```

no matter what i try the file is always corrupted. Not able to open in Acrobat reader.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an encoding problem.

```
Map<String, DataHandler> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachments();

String charsetPartStr = attachments.get("content").getContentType();
Files.write(path, bytes, StandardOpenOption.APPEND,  Charset.forName(charsetPartStr));
```

Keep the media-type of the part an use it when you write your files.